# Bigcommerce Custom Header Panel not loading Header properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, bigcommerce

I have blog and want to place custom meta tags on main blog page. but bigcommerce has meta tags in HTMLHead.html panel that are replaced with contents coming dynamically. I have proper meta tags values on  any single blog post but i need same thing on main blog page where all posts are listings. when i created a custom header panel BLOGHead.html to replace it with HTMLHead.html on blog page it generates an error and store is not loaded properly for that page but other complete store is working fine with same contents in HTMLHead.html.
can any one help me and tell me where is the main issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a custom Head panel that replaces that file. You could try using JavaScript to say use the dynamic meta contents or do nothing unless X value is present to indicate the blog. Google does execute JavaScript in crawls so it should uncover this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add new meta tags, or change the values in meta tags that would normally be set in the HTMLHead panel?

If you're adding a distinct set of new meta tags for the blog page, you can just stick them in the main template file...look for blog.html in the root of your template directory.  Just stick the meta tags underneath the reference to %%Panel.HTMLHead%%.

With that said, I've been able to swap out the HTMLHead panel for custom ones in the past with no issue.  Your problem may have been related to your filename.  I've used custom panels like 'HTMLHead-checkout' or 'HTMLHead-success' on various templates before...so the key might be to start the name of your custom panel with HTMLHead.  Just a thought based on my experiences.